# Exact Diff. Equation $ \frac{d y}{d x}=\frac{x y^{2}-\cos x \sin x}{y\left(1-x^{2}\right)} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Solve:$$
\frac{d y}{d x}=\frac{x y^{2}-\cos x \sin x}{y\left(1-x^{2}\right)}.$$
$${(xy^2 -\cos x\sin x)dx+y(1-x^2)dy=0}.$$

So the first term, $(xy^2 -\cos x\sin x)dx$ is $=M(x,y)$  and the second, $ y(1-x^{2} )dy$ term is $=N(x,y)$.

If $
\frac {\partial {M}}{\partial y}=-2xy$ ;   $\frac {\partial N}{\partial x}=-2xy$ there is an exact solution

$$ f(x,y)=\int M(x,y)dx +g(x) = \frac{x^2y^2}{2}+\frac{cos^2x}{2}+g(x)$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=N(x,y)=y(1-x^2)$$

$$f(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{2}(1-x^2)+g(x)$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-xy^2+g'(x)=-xy^2-\cos x\sin x; g'(x)=-\cos x \sin x$$

$$g(x)= \int -\cos x\sin x dx =-\frac{cos^2x}{2} $$

$$f(x,y) = -\frac{cos^2x}{2} + \frac{y^2(1-x^2)}{2}$$

Am I using the terms properly and is my solution correct?

Comment: Normally names don't matter much but $\mu$ is a particularly bad name here because it is widely used for integrating factors. Anyway, just take the gradient of your solution and see what you get to check it. At the moment I think I see a small issue.

Comment: I changed it to avoid any confusion, thanks for the heads up about its use for integrating factors. This was the gradient, how would I compare this to verify ?  \begin{bmatrix}\left(-\cos \left(x\right)\sin \left(x\right)-y^2x\right)\\ y\left(-x^2+1\right)\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Those terms simplify to $xy^2+cos(x)sin(x) $ and $ y(1-x^2)$

Comment: Yep you had a sign mistake now it looks good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{d y}{d x}=\frac{x y^{2}-\cos x \sin x}{y\left(1-x^{2}\right)}.$$
$$y(1-x^2){d y}=x y^{2}dx-\cos x \sin xdx$$
$$dy^2-2x^2yd y-2xy^2dx=2\cos x d\cos x$$
$$dy^2-(x^2d y^2+y^2dx^2)=2\cos x d\cos x$$
$$y^2-x^2 y^2-\cos^2 x =C$$
Your solution looks correct to me.